# Loop through subfiles and get result of of the sum of contents in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6, sum

I'm struggling to get the sum of the subfiles. The code below currently returns the sum of `a.txt` and all its subfiles, supposing that the contents of `a.txt` is

```
1
b.txt
```

the contents of `b.txt` is

```
2
c.txt
```

and the contents of `c.txt` is

```
3
```

I'd like to also get the sum of `b.txt` and all of its subfiles, the sum of `c.txt` and all of its subfiles, and so on and so forth for all the files that exist. So the output would be: the sum of `a.txt` and its subfiles is `sum`, the sum of `b.txt` and its subfiles is `sum`, the sum of `c.txt` and its subfiles is `sum`, and so on...

My code below:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const file = 'a.txt'

let output = (file) => {
  let data = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8')
    .split('\n')
    .reduce((array, i) => {
      if (i.match(/.txt$/)) {
        let intArr = array.concat(output(i))
        return intArr
      } else if (i.match(/^\d+$/)) {
        array.push(parseInt(i, 10));
      }
      return array;
    }, [])

    return data
}

console.log(output(file))

const sum = output(file)

console.log(sum.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))
```

Also, any suggestions for improving this code are welcome.

Comment: What happens now?

Comment: Can you give some more details about your files? Are they always of the form `number\nfile.txt`. Can they have more than one file or number?

Comment: Yes, the files would always be in this form.

Comment: If they are always of this form why are you testing with regular expressions and adding with reduce? Why not just split into `[count, next_file]`. Your sample code makes it look the files might have more than one count or more than one child file.

Comment: Hi, yes, sorry. I should be able to handle the files no matter how many integers or txt files there are nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be viewed as a pretty standard graph search. Your code starts to do that but there's a few places it can be changed to make it a little easier.

Below is a depth first search starting with a particular file and keeping track of a counts object. The function parses the file just like yours, adds the numbers the `counts` object. Then it recurses. When the recursion unwinds it add the resulting child's counts to the parents. In the end it returns the `counts` object which should have the total + subpages for all pages. It doesn't do any error checking for simplicity and it's not clear what should happen if two children both reference the same grandchild - should it be counted twice? Either was it should be easy to adjust.

I made mocked version of `fs.readFileSync` to the code would run in the snippet and be easier to see:

```js
// fake fs for readFileSync
let fs = {
    files: {
        "a.txt": "1\nb.txt",
        "b.txt": "2\nc.txt",
        "c.txt": "3",
        "d.txt": "2\n10\ne.txt\nf.txt",
        "e.txt": "1",
        "f.txt": "5\n7\ng.txt",
        "g.txt": "1\na.txt"
    },
    readFileSync(file) { return this.files[file]}
}

function dfs(file, counts = {}) {
    // parse a sinlge file into object
    // {totals: sum_allthenumbers, files:array_of_files}
    let data = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8').split('\n')
    let {total, files} = data.reduce((a, c) => {
        if(c.match(/^\d+$/)) a.total += parseInt(c)
        else if(c.match(/.txt$/)) a.files.push(c)
        return a
    },{total: 0, files:[]})

    // add the total counts for this file
    counts[file] = total      
    // recurse on children files
    for (let f of files) {
       if (counts.hasOwnProperty(f)) continue // don't look at files twice if there are cycles
        let c = dfs(f, counts) 
        counts[file] += c[f]  // children return the counts object, add childs count to parent
    }
    // return count object
    return counts 
}

console.log("original files starting with a.txt")
console.log(dfs('a.txt'))

console.log("more involved graph starts with d.txt")
console.log(dfs('d.txt'))
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much for explaining this. You've helped me a lot. :D @MarkMeyer